# DecimalSeparator in PrimeNG Spinner does not work

Tags: primeng, primeng-spinner

When I set decimal separator to anything (eg comma), it reverts back to period on blur. Even clicking increment and decrement, it does not use comma but period.

Moreover, if I am using `decimalSeparator` and `step` properties together, in which format should I set the `step`?

Here's what my html looks like...

`<p-spinner [(ngModel)]='selected' [decimalSeparator]="','" [step]="'0,1'"></p-spinner>`

I have tried the values without quote & variable as well but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `<p-spinner [(ngModel)]="selected" [step]="0.1" [formatInput]="true" thosandSeparator="," decimalSeparator="."></p-spinner>` ?

Comment: This definitely works. 

I want to use comma as a decimal separator instead of period. That doesn't work. When I specify comma as the decimal separator and set the step as "0,1" it does not work. Basically what I want is to use comma as the decimal separator and on clicking Up/Down arrow key, it should increment/decrement by the specified step but with the specified Decimal Separator.

Comment: I was going through the source code of Spinner and found this...

```Object.defineProperty(Spinner.prototype, "decimalSeparator", {
        set: function (value) {
            console.warn("decimalSeparator property is removed Spinner as Spinner does not format the value anymore.");
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });```

Does that mean decimalSeparator is not supported anymore?

Comment: It seems to be...

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG 7 doesn't support decimalSeparator and thousandSeparator. You can make an upgrade to PrimeNG 8.0.2, then you can use the parameters and formatInput too.